# Homology spectral sequence for function space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences, homology

The question is in the title. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two pointed connected CW-complexes. I was wondering if there exists a spectral sequence computing the homology of the function space $$H_{\ast}(map_{\ast}(X,Y);k) $$
where $k$ is a fixed field. Could we say something interesting in the case when $H_{\ast}(X;k)$ is trivial.

For simplicity we can assume that $X$ and $Y$ are simply connected.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative spectral sequence for $H_∗(map_∗(X,Y);k)$ can be constructed using the approach in [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1999-351-03/S0002-9947-99-02405-8/S0002-9947-99-02405-8.pdf) of mine (apols for self-promotion). Actually, this spectral sequence is discussed already in an [earlier paper of Bendersky and Gitler](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1991-326-01/S0002-9947-1991-1010881-8/S0002-9947-1991-1010881-8.pdf). This spectral sequence converges in the same cases as the Anderson spectral sequence that is alluded to in John Klein's answer. An explicit comparison of the two spectral sequences [was given by Podkorytov](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.2478%2Fs11533-011-0084-1.pdf). See also [the paper of Ahearn and Kuhn](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.agt/1513882737) that gives a nice introduction to the spectral sequence, and studies its structure in detail.

I think that the approach in this paper can answer the question on what happens when $H_*(X;k)=0$. Indeed, the spectral sequence is based on the following model for the chains on $map_*(X, Y)$. Let $C_*(Y)$ denote the (reduced) complex of singular chains on $Y$ and $C^*(X)$ denote the reduced singular cochains on $X$. Let $\mathcal E$ be the category of non-empty finite sets and surjective functions, and let $\mathcal E^t$ be the "twisted arrow category" of $\mathcal E^t$. An object of $\mathcal E^t$ is a surjection of sets $i\twoheadrightarrow j$ and a morphism from $i\twoheadrightarrow j$ to $s\twoheadrightarrow t$ consists of sujections $i\twoheadrightarrow s$ and $t\twoheadrightarrow j$ that make the evident square commute (note the twist in the directions of the arrows).

There is an evident contravariant functor from $\mathcal E^t$ to chain complexes that sends $i\twoheadrightarrow j$ to $C^*(X^{\wedge j}) \otimes C_*(Y^{\wedge i}) \otimes k$. The point is that the homotopy limit of this functor is quasi-isomorphic to $C_*(map_*(X,Y);k)$ when $X$ is a finite q-dimensional complex and $Y$ is $q-1$-connected. Now, suppose $H_*(X;k)=0$. Then $C^*(X^{\wedge j})\otimes k$ is an acyclic complex for all $j$, and therefore the homotopy limit is acyclic as well. So we may conclude the following

**Claim**: Suppose $X$ is a finite $q$-dimensional complex and $Y$ is a $q-1$-connected space. Suppose furthermore that $H_*(X;k)$ is trivial. Then $H_*(map_*(X,Y);k)$ is trivial.

Remark 1: it is not necessary to assume that $X$ is simply connected.

Remark 2: The conclusion should hold whenever either one of the spectral sequences converges. The condition that $X$ is q-dimensional and $Y$ is $q-1$-connected is the standard condition that guarantees convergence. But when $k={\mathbb Z}/p$ there also are results about "exotic convergence" of these types of spectral sequences that may be relevant.

Comment: Hi Greg, if I'm reading your paper right the correct bound for convergence is that $X$ is $q$-dimensional and $Y$ is $q$-connected, or am I missing something?

Comment: Dan, you are right. In my paper I assumed that the connectivity of $Y$ is at least the dimension of $X$. In this case strong conversion follows from Goodwillie's theory of analytic functors. In my answer here I was following the other answer, which said that the Anderson-Bousfield spectral sequence converges when $X$ is $s$-dimensional and $Y$ is $s-1$-connected. I am rather confident that the two spectral sequences have the same convergence properties. This follows for example by Podkorytov's work. But I did not know it when I wrote that paper. (continued)

Comment: Furthermore, I checked the papers of Anderson and Bousfield. Anderson actually says that the connectivity of Y has to be at least the dimension of X, but Bousfield attributes the slightly better statement to Anderson! This can't be right if $Y$ is not nilpotent. For example, if $Y=S^1\vee S^1$, and $X=S^1$, then the spectral sequence will converge to the nilpotent completion of $F_2$. But: Bousfield proves the stronger convergence result when $Y$ is simple. As I said, I am pretty sure that the Goodwillie tower will converge in these cases as well, even though I did not prove it in my paper.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Is it possible that Bousfield just misquoted Anderson? In the result Bousfield states as being more general in §4.2 he has the assumption that $\widetilde H^m(X,\pi_{m+n}(Y))=0$ for $n \leq 0$ which would fit better with $\dim(X) \leq \mathrm{connectivity}(Y)$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $X$ be a simplicial set and $Y$ a space (or simplicial set) . Then $F_\ast(X,Y)$ is a cosimplicial space and we can consider its homology spectral sequence. Bousfield gave conditions for when this will converge to the homology
of $F_\ast(X,Y)$ with field coefficients. See here:

On the Homology Spectral Sequence of a Cosimplicial Space
A. K. Bousfield
American Journal of Mathematics
Vol. 109, No. 2 (Apr., 1987), pp. 361-394

[This is not my area of expertise, but if I remember correctly, convergence is guaranteed if, say, $X$ is $s$-dimensional and finite, and $Y$ is $(s-1)$-connected.]

**Added:**

See page 371 of Bousfield's paper, where he attributes the spectral sequence and its convergence to Anderson. Bousfield also claims the $E_2$-term may be identified when $k=\Bbb Z/p$ in terms of the graded vector space $H_\ast(X;k)$ and the algebra $H^\ast(Y;k)$ provided that the latter is "Hopf-like:" i.e., a tensor product of exterior and polynomial algebras.

Comment: What can we say concretely in the case when $H_{\ast}(X;k)$ is trivial ?

Comment: @tictac I think you'll have to go back and dig up Bousfield's paper list as [5] in  the paper I cited. Look at what I "added" in my answer. Judging from what Bousfield wrote, when $k =\Bbb Z/p$, $H_\ast(X;k)$ is trivial and $H^\ast(Y;k)$ is Hopf-like, it looks to me that in this case $H_\ast(F_\ast(X,Y);k)$ will be trivial when $X$ is $q$-dimensional and $Y$ is $(q-1)$-connected.